# Is there some way to get app name when running in heroku?

Tags: heroku

I do a project that runs in heroku.
I try to oprate the app's config bt itself, that need the app name or id and the API key of Heroku.
Now I read the app name from xxxxx.herokuapp.com, but it will not work when using custmer domain.
So, is there some way to know 'who am I' in heroku?

Comment: I can get info of all apps in my account, but I just can not know which app is itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata

```
heroku labs:enable runtime-dyno-metadata -a <app name>
```

The information you need will be available through the environment variable `$HEROKU_APP_NAME`

Comment: oh I see, thank you. That may works,   
But my project is share to others, they deploy my project to heroku, they may not use the shell to oprate, it is too difficult for them.  
I will store the name in config.

Comment: this gets the HEROKU_DYNO_ID but not the app name :'(